# How save in an array the following 100 received value after a determined received string in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qtserialport

I'm a newbie in C++ and Qt. I want to save in an array the value received in a serialport after I received the string: "Data".
I'm using the terminal example so the serialport works properly.

```
The read function in the Example is the same:
void MainWindow::readData()
{
    QByteArray data = serial->readAll();
    console->putData(data);

}
```

How can I modify it? thanks!!!

Comment: Is this synchronous or asynchronous? what is the format of your packets?

Comment: Is asynchronous and the packets is type int.

Comment: what determines the start and end of your transmission? do you use a checksum?

Comment: Sincerly, I don't know how works the teminal example. If i sent some string with my microcontroller to the PC, all I sent is plot to terminal.

Comment: Rafael is right, most of devices has start/end delimiter for messages. Soemtimes you can configure them. I think classical values for that are 0x02 and 0x03 but I'm not sure and it totally depends on the device. double check the documentation and the answer from Rafael seems to be a good start.

Answer (score 1):

If your manual sending the data i recommend you add a start of frame delimiter and an end of frame delimiter and checksum preferably.

```
 QByteArray packet_storage;
```

just declare it the where you declare serial.
`StartOfMessage and EndOfMessage` will depend on your device.
I don't know what your transmitting. Hopefully you can figure out from the documentation of your device what your sending out.

as for me i am using

```
 enum Constants
   {
       StartOfMessage  = '\x02',   /* Value of byte that marks the start of a message */
       EndOfMessage    = '\x03',   /* Value of byte that marks the end of a message */
       CarridgeReturn  = '\x0D',   /* Carridge return is first byte of end of line */
       LineFeed        = '\x0A',   /* Line feed is second byte of end of line */
       NullChar        = '\0'      /* Null Character */
   };

void MainWindow::readData()
{
     // read all 
     QByteArray data = serial->readAll();

     // store all read data packet_storage is a QByteArray
     packet_storage.append(data);

     int start_index = 0;
     int end_index = 0;

     // process packet if not empty
     if(!packet_storage.isEmpty())
     {
         if( packet_storage.contains(StartOfMessage) &&  packet_storage.contains(EndOfMessage))
         {
                    start_index = packet_storage.indexOf(StartOfMessage,0);
                    end_index   = packet_storage.indexOf(EndOfMessage,0);

                    int length = 0;

                    for (int i=start_index; i <= end_index; i++)
                    {
                        length++;
                    }

                    // get data
                    QByteArray dt = packet_storage.mid(start_index,length);

                    // do your processing here. 
                    // store in vector write to file etc.
                    processpacket(dt);                         

                    packet_storage.remove(start_index,dt.size());

           }

       }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Rafael! Now I try to use it!

Comment: Sorry but how can define packet_storage and start and end_index? =)